# Getting position of window with font increase

Tags: qt, winapi

i have a problem with getting position of qt window in Windows while i have text size increased in windows settings.

So i'm developing an Qt app for multimonitor setup, the app monitors it's position and returns to screen to which is associated.

I already tried to get window position with:

1.Qt function `geometry()`

2.Qt function `frameGeometry()`

3.Inside Qt window calss `this->pos()`

4.WinApi function `GetWindowRect`

All of them work fine when font size in Windows settings is set to 100%.
But when i change font size to 125% and more only on the main midle screenn, position returned by that functions are wierd, too big something like from -6800 to 6000 in pixels with font size 175%, when i have 3 monitors 1920x1080 in row from -1920 to 1920(rightest screen position) and 3840 rightest pixel column.

CCD Api returns me that i still have from -1920 to 1920 with font size increased. and so says registry in 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\UnitedVideo\CONTROL\VIDEO\`

So the question is, how to get window position when font is incresed ?
And who is wrong here me, doing wrong thing or Windows have a bug?

Comment: [High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows).

Comment: Not 100% i understand but i think you are looking for: _QPoint pos = widget->mapToGlobal(widget->pos());_ see the doc: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal Hope this helps

Comment: @zla: `GetWindowRect` already returns screen coordinates. Translating from client to screen coordinates doesn't solve the issue. The issue is caused by virtualization of pixel coordinates on high DPI displays.

Comment: @Zlatomir QPoint pos = widget->mapToGlobal(widget->pos()); gives only crazier numbers something from -6000 up to 12 000

Comment: @IInspectable thank you for suggestion, but all High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows is for windows 8.1 and higher, but i need to support _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601. It helped me to find solution in Qt framework

Comment: That's not correct. [SetProcessDPIAware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setprocessdpiaware) was introduced in Windows Vista, for example.